# Adding file to a list that has already previously been deleted in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, file, fileinputstream

I have a custom `FileInput` class in my `React` code. Now If I add a `File` with this `FileInput` to an `Array`, then remove the `File` from that `List` and then try to add the same `File` again, it is no longer being added to the `Array`.

FileInput.js

```
let FileInput = (props) => {
    const { className, children } = props;

    let attributes = {
        ...props,

        type: 'file',
        className: 'form-input-file',
    };

    delete attributes.children;

    return (
      <label className={'form-input-file-parent form-input-clickable' + (className ? ' ' + className : '')}>
        <input {...attributes} />
        {children}
      </label>
    )
};


export default FileInput;
```

And then the code where I add/remove:

```
  <FileInput
    multiple
    onChange={onAttachmentsAdded}
  >
    Add File
  </FileInput>

onAttachmentsAdded = (evt) => {
  this.setState({
    attachments: [
      ...attachments,
      ...evt.target.files,
    ],
  });
};

onAttachmentsRemove = (file) => {
    const array = [...attachments];
    const index = array.indexOf(file);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({
        attachments: array,
      });
    }
  };
```

Created a `CodeSandbox` :

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-remove-add-file-etbh5)

Add a file, remove the file then try to add the same File again.

Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issue here was that when selecting a new `File`, `onChange` was called, then the `File` was deleted and when the same `File` was selected again.. `onChange` was not called because `File` did not actually change, the solution was to add this line, into the `FileInput`.

```
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.currentTarget.value = null;
  }}
```